# Android App Internal Test Publishing shows "App is not available for your device" on Google Play

Tags: google-play-console, google-play-internal-testing

I have developed an application using Ionic 7 and Capacitor 4. I recently published the app for internal testing. I added the tester's email to the internal testing group, and they successfully received the invitation to join the testing group. However, when the tester tries to install the app on their device, they encounter an error message on Google Play saying "App is not available for your device," even though the app is compatible with the operating system.

[image: Google Play Internal Testing]
[image: Software information]
[image: Compatibility]
[image: App is not available for your device]

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that you recently published the app. When is the recent? It could be that your internal testing app is still being reviewed by Google / in draft that's why your tester could not access it.

Since your last screenshot is also shown as (unreviewed) so I assume this might be the case. (Although it's just an assumption but you can consider to reach out to Play Console support on twitter and ask them about the status of your app? They will usually tell you if the app has been approved/still in review so I think that helps with your situation a bit.) :)

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been resolved. We tested the application on several other devices, and it worked fine. It appears that the problem was specific to the device(Samsung SM-J530F) used by the initial tester.

Comment: But you never solved it that the app could be installed on that Samsung device, right? I have the exact same problem with a Nokia G50 (Android 13). No clue why it says not to be available for that device, where on all other devices it installed without any problems.